# ContourPlot3D, Characteristics of PDE

Tags: plotting

The aim is to plot the solution of a PDE with initial value along with its characteristics and initial value.

$x u_x - y u_y = 0$ on the line $x=y=u=t$, i.e. $u(t,t)=t$ $(t > 0)$.

Then the general solution is given by $u(x,y) = \Phi(xy)$, on the line by $u_p(x,y) = \sqrt{xy}$.

First I define the solution of the PDE by

```
In[1]:= sol7212a = DSolve[{x*D[u[x, y], x] - y*D[u[x, y], y] == 0}, u, {x, y}]
 Out[1]= {{u -> Function[{x, y}, C[1][x y]]}}
```

and then the plot.

```
In[2]:= Show[
  Plot3D[ 

    Evaluate[u[x, y] /. sol7212a /. {C[1][t_] -> Sqrt[t]}[[1]]], {x, -4,  4}, 
      {y, -4, 4}, Mesh -> True,  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["LakeColors"][#3] &)],   
    ParametricPlot3D[{t, t, t}, {t, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> Cyan],   
    Evaluate[ Table[ContourPlot3D[{z == Sqrt[x*y], x* y == C}, {x, -4, 4}, 
        {y, -4,  4}, {z, -4, 4}, Contours -> {0}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0], 
        Mesh -> None,  BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, 
        {1, 2} -> {{Green, Tube[.03]}}}, Boxed -> False], {C, 1, 10, 1}]
  ], 
LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Museo Sans"), Boxed -> False]
```

This produces the desired result.

[image: Plot]

Thus, the first `Evaluate[]` draws the solution surface of the PDE and `ParametricPlot3D[]` the line $(t,t,t)$. The second `Evaluate[]` calculates the characteristics for constants 1,2,...,10.

But the `ContourPlot3D` command is very slow. I am not even able to resize or turn the produced image. Is there a better way to implement the characteristics?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `ContourStyle` option. After changing

```
ContourStyle -> Opacity[0]
```

to

```
ContourStyle -> None
```

the plot is generated normally and in a fraction of time. The result can be manipulated and exported normally as well.

Thanks, wueb.